# Unable to open node js serialport on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, arduino

I'm working on node app with socket.io & serialport dependency for arduino.
I have following sever.js for node

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var SerialPort = require('serialport').SerialPort;
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);  //pass a http.Server instance



// "process.env.PORT" to set port by Heroku
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('listening on:' + port);
});

// Serial Port
var serialPort = new SerialPort("/dev/cu.usbserial-XXXXXXXX", {
    baudrate: 115200
});

...... Some code here ..............


serialPort.on('close', function(err) {
    console.log('port closed');
});

//serialport open
serialPort.open(function () {
  console.log('port open');
});
```

I have also set dependency for `serverport` in package.json.

This code works fine on my localhost server but When I try to run this code on Heroku, I get following error :

```
events.js:85
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
Error: Cannot open /dev/cu.usbserial-XXXXXXXX
at Error (native)
```

Why so ? Is there any specific requirement for Heroku-serverport ?